# Do we need an [inconsistency]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inconsistency)  has only 149 questions, 1 follower, no wiki and its meaning varies. Is it any good?

Comment: Completely useless.

Comment: .. 1 follower. Can someone check if this always has been the same person? (Applied Logic dictates it should not.)

Comment: To be inconsistent with the otherwise consistent consensus: Yes, we need!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since there was a consistent consensus that the [inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inconsistency) tag was not needed, I've consistently removed it — almost consistently not doing anything else (one question got a [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag added).

There shouldn't be any questions tagged [inconsistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inconsistency) any more.

Comment: It's a pity that this answer has not been upvoted consistently. The sole downvote is in my view, inconsistent with the consistent dedication Jonathan has put into eradicating the tag from the site.

Comment: Isn't it inconsistent that you consistently removed [tag:inconsistency], while you did inconsistently leave [tag:consistency] untouched?

Comment: [consistency](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/consistency/info) appears to be applied correct for 28 or so out of the first 30 questions (statistic outliers [#1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600152/how-ensure-front-end-and-back-end-object-consistency-of-different-programming-la) and [#2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837504/keeping-timer-events-equally-spaced)).

Comment: @Theolodis: Since 'consistency' was consistently unmentioned in the question, there was no clear mandate to do anything with it, and 'consistency' has a tag wiki that makes sense and is applied (more or less) consistently to questions for which the tag is appropriate.  Therefore, it would have been inconsistent to remove that tag (especially as none of the questions tagged 'inconsistency' were also tagged 'consistency', which is surprisingly consistent for an inconsistently applied tag like 'inconsistency').  :D